# If a space is connected in a topology, given a coarser topology, is it connected?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

Question:

> Let $\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{S}$ be two topologies on $X$, and
>   $\mathcal{T}$ is finer than $\mathcal{S}$
>
> If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is connected, what about $(X, \mathcal{S})$?

Well, if $\mathcal{S}$ is coarser than $\mathcal{T}$, then $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$

This means every open set in $\mathcal{S}$ is in $\mathcal{T}$

Then $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is connected if there are no nontrivial, disjoint open sets $A, B \subset X$ such that $A \sqcup B = X$ [Edited per comment]

Since there is no such disjoint open sets $A,B \in \mathcal{T}$,  and $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ $\implies$ there is no such open sets $A,B \in \mathcal{S}$. Necessarily $(X, \mathcal{S})$ is connected.

Is my assessment correct?

Comment: Yes, that'sl fine

Comment: The idea is fine, but you didn't say it quite right: there are no non-trivial disjoint open sets $A,B\subseteq X$ such that $A\cup B=X$. That *such that* clause is crucial.

Comment: You proved the statement that if $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is connected and $\mathcal{S}$ is coarser than $\mathcal{T}$, then $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is connected. The contrapositive is if $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is disconnected, then $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is disconnected or $\mathcal{S}$ is not coarser than $\mathcal{T}$. Assuming that $\mathcal{S}$ is coarser than $\mathcal{T}$ forces us to conclude that $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is disconnected.

Comment: The contrapositive makes sense because there exist non-trivial disjoint open sets $A,B \subseteq X$ such that $A \cup B = X$ when $X$ is given the topology $\mathcal{S}$. Since $\mathcal{S}$ is coarser than $\mathcal{T}$, the same holds true for the sets $A$ and $B$ when $X$ is given the topology $\mathcal{T}$.